# Set delegation in Gmail via API with Python

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to get a Python script to run which is setting delegations in Gmail.

As a basic starting point, I used the "[Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)" from Google.

```python
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """

    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:

        # Create a Gmail service client
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # Set delegation for a specific sender
        sender_email = 'sender@domain.com'
        delegate_email = 'delegate@domain.com'

        settings = {
            'delegateEmail': delegate_email
        }

        result = service.users().settings().sendAs().update(userId='me', sendAsEmail=sender_email, body=settings).execute()
        print('Delegation set successfully!')
    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I created a project and the authorization credentials for a desktop application.

When I started the script for the first time, I got the following error message:

```
"Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority". Details: "[{'message': 'Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]"
```

So I checked the [Gmail API specification](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) and I saw that for this scope a Service Account was needed. I [created a Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) and added the scope into Google Workspace.

After trying the script with the newly downloaded Jason for the Service Account, the following error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\quickstart.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\quickstart.py", line 31, in main
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 201, in from_client_secrets_file
    return cls.from_client_config(client_config, scopes=scopes, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 159, in from_client_config
    raise ValueError("Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.")
ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.
```

What is meant with "installed app"? The OAuth client for the project I created is set to "desktop app".

Is something wrong with the code, or is it the Service Account setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use delegate user, you need to use impersonation (delegated domain-wide authority) as mention in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.delegates/create).

You need to do some changes to your code, to use the services account to authenticate. You can see the example in Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

This is a working example code:

*Note: In this sample, user1 is grating access to user2 to access to the inbox.*

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2 import service_account



SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing']


def main():

    # Location and name of the JSON file / Key of the services account. 

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'ServiceAccountCredentials.json'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    
    # User that will be impersonated
    # Email address of who will grant permission to access to the inbox
    
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user1@domain.com')


    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)

        # Email address of how is getting permission to manage the inbox 

        body = {
            'delegateEmail': 'user2@domain.com',
            'verificationStatus': 'accepted'
            }
        request = service.users().settings().delegates().create(userId='me', body=body).execute()
        print(request)
       

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thx for your input. I tried to run your code, but I get the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'array_list' from 'user_list' (C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\user_list\__init__.py)` . I'm using Python 3.11.4 , and I did `pip install user_list` . Is it possible that the module is not compatible with Python 3.11. ?

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with a list of users, let me correct the code

Comment: @x0100, Thanks for letting me know. I just remove the import `from user_list import array_list`, and it should work. I was using a list of users in my domain as a test and I completely forgot to remove it when I was sanitizing the sample code.